# Build hmac sha256 hashing algorithm in node.js

Tags: node.js, http-headers, sha256, hmac, cryptojs

I am using [Bold Commerce Webhooks](https://docs.boldapps.net/subscriptions/integration/#securing-webhooks) to subscribe to subscription events in my store. They give documentation about how their request signatures are generated in PHP:

```
$now = time(); // current unix timestamp
$json = json_encode($payload, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $now.'.'.$json, $signingKey);
```

I'm trying to recreate the hash on my side in node.js. From my research I've figured out the following so far, which I believe is pretty close, but doesn't match yet:

```
const hash = request.header("X-Bold-Signature")!;

const SECRET = "my-secret-api-key";
const body = request.body;
const time = request.header("timestamp")!;

const mySignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRET).update(time + '.' + body).digest("hex");

if (mySignature !== request.header("X-Bold-Signature")!) {
    //...
}
```

I've also tried using `JSON.stringify(body)` which changes the hash but still doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

It matched with this code.

```
const hash = crypto
  .createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
  .update(timestamp + '.' + JSON.stringify(body))
  .digest('hex');
```

Note that unlike shopify, do not use rawbody.